# Make outbound call with twilio sip trunk using python flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, sip, twilio-twiml

I am new to twilio and flask and am trying to make outbound calls in twilio with the code below.

@

```
app.route("/", methods=['GET'])

def call():

    account_sid = 'abcd'
    auth_token = '123'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    auth = ('1000', '1000pqr')
    call = client.calls.create(
        to='+919874561230',
        from_='+14567891230',
        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml'
    )
    print(call.sid)
    return jsonify({"success": 1, 'message': 'SSSSSS'})
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5005)
```

Everything works perfectly but I want to make call through elastic sip trunk means the above shows the call direction as Outgoing API I want Trunking Terminating.

Answer (score 0):

To make a call through Elastic SIP Trunking, you'll need to update the `from_` parameter in the `client.calls.create()` method to be your SIP URI.

Here's an example of how you can update your code to use an Elastic SIP Trunking URI:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def call():
    account_sid = 'abcd'
    auth_token = '123'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    auth = ('1000', '1000pqr')
    call = client.calls.create(
        to='+919874561230',
        from_='sip:your-sip-uri@your-twilio-trunking-domain',
        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml'
    )
    print(call.sid)
    return jsonify({"success": 1, 'message': 'SSSSSS'})

if __name__ == "main":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5005)
```

Replace `your-sip-uri` and `your-twilio-trunking-domain` with the SIP URI and Trunking Domain of your Elastic SIP Trunking connection. Also, make sure that you've properly configured your SIP Trunk in the Twilio Console.

Comment: 'sip:freepbxsf.pstn.twilio.com@1000@125.59..4' where 1000 = extension and 125.59.1.4 is  domain.It shows  in vaild from number

Comment: @JD This might be a typo but are you using that exact code? Because the the domain you provided is 125.59..4 There are 2 periods consecutively. Could you verify that for me?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion,it is a typo and yes I am using the same code.

Comment: The issue may be because you have two '@' symbols in the SIP URI. In a SIP URI, the first '@' symbol separates the username/extension from the domain name. Any additional '@' symbols are used to separate additional parameters. In this case, it looks like you have specified the extension number as '1000', but then you have another '@' symbol after it. This may be causing the Twilio API to interpret the URI incorrectly.

Also you told that you are using the same code. Please change `125.59..4` to `125.59.1.4`.

Comment: Is there any other way to get  the call direction to be truncking termination not Outgoing API using code.

Comment: You can use Elastic SIP Trunk instead of instead of Twilio API.